# Entity framework many to one?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-relationship

I am trying to create a new table which will be used by any other tables.
The table name will be Uploads. I will increase Id field manually for each source table record.
For example: I will add a new booking record with 3 uploads. These 3 uploads will have the same Id.
After that when I create a new venue record with 2 uploads. I will increase the Uploads.Id, and then these 2 uploads will have the same Id.

As this table will be used by other tables, I don't want to create a navigator for each of the tables. Is there any way to make it?

Hope you're clear about what I meant to ask. Instance models are below;

```
    public class Upload
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}



public class Bookings {

    public int Id {get;set;}
   
    public int? UploadId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Upload> Uploads { get; set; }
}

public class Venues {

    public int Id {get;set;}
   
    public int? UploadId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Upload> Uploads { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What is the difference between Bookings  and Venues? They look the same for me

Comment: Actually, they have different fields. I just tried to shorten it up to make it clear

Comment: "These 3 uploads will have the same Id" what it means? why you need to add 3 the same uploads?

Comment: You didn't tell the most important if one upload record will have only one parent table, or the same upload can be used in severall tables?

Comment: It was an example. What I meant to say is that, when I create a new Venue, I will be able to upload files. When I upload 1, 2, or more files, they will all have the same Id on the Uploads table. As the Uploads table will be generic, I don't want to have VenueId or BookingId columns

Comment: Each record will have one parent table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you could add a `BookingId` / `VenueId` to your `Upload` table, as per the other answer on this question.

Since EF Core only supports navigations that correspond to a primary / foreign key. If you want to ensure that your `Upload`s don't know anything about where they are used, you would need to introduce a new table to represent a collection of `Upload`s.

This would also allow you to use an identity field to auto-number each collection.

```cs
public class UploadSet
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<Upload> Uploads { get; set; }
}
public class Upload
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public int SetId { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Bookings 
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public int? UploadSetId {get;set;}
   public virtual UploadSet UploadSet { get; set; }
}
```

Note that this schema will not prevent you from accidently linking the same set of uploads to more than one parent.

Comment: I thought about using an alternate key to skip the extra table. But that would only work if you only had one parent table.

Comment: Thanks, yesterday, I just could be able to fix it by doing this

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want to create a navigator for each of the tables.

By default, **a relationship** will be created when **there is a navigation property** discovered on a type.

> I will add a new booking record with 3 uploads. These 3 uploads will have the same Id.

1. If **Bookings and Upload** have a **one-to-many** relationship, which means that **a Booking** can have **multiple Uploads**, then you should modify your Model to:

   - ```
     public class Upload
     {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int? BookingId { get; set; }
        public int? VenueId { get; set; }
     }
     public class Bookings 
     {
        public int Id {get;set;}
        public virtual ICollection<Upload> Uploads { get; set; }
     }
     public class Venues 
     {
        public int Id {get;set;}
        public virtual ICollection<Upload> Uploads { get; set; }
     }
     ```

I suggest you **[click this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key)** to view the relationship defines how two entities relate to each other.

Comment: Thanks, but I implied that I don't want to have navigation properties on the Upload table